# Demonic correspondence: Best practices when defining devils in TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, best-practices

[image: angels and devils]

`tikzsymbols` defines a series of symbols which can be used in text (or nested in larger pictures) and which can be customised in various ways e.g. scaling size, choice of colours etc.

For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (yellow) {\color{yellow}\Innocey};
    \node [right=5pt of yellow] {\color{purple}\Innocey[13][][pink]};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: two innocents]

What is the best way to set up symbols of this kind? In particular, what is the best way to code symbols not covered by such existing packages? I intend this question to be a general one but I am especially interested in symbols which are designed to complement those provided by such existing solutions.

For example, suppose that I wanted to create a 'devil' symbol to complement the 'angel' symbol above. What is the best way to go about this?

Initially, I did this by modifying the code `tikzsymbols` uses to produce the haloed smiley. However, this depends on internal macros which disappeared or were renamed when the package was updated. So I had to recode my symbol to reflect the changes.

On the other hand, if I do not use these macros, I'm not certain how to ensure that my extension complements the symbols provided by the package. For example, I want the two smileys to be based on circles of the same size if I specify the same scaling factor in each case. And I want the basic line widths to match and so on. If I code my symbol from scratch, I worry that, although the code will be less susceptible to breaking when `tikzsymbols` is updated, it will be less likely that the style of my symbol will continue to match that of the package's symbols.

For completeness, here is my updated code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,positioning,fit,backgrounds}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\makeatletter
  \tkzsymbls@Declare@Robust@Commandx{Devilish}[3][1=1,2={opacity=0},3=red,usedefault]{% based on \Innocey from tikzsymbols - updated 2014-11-15 due to changes in tikzsymbols (untested here but tested in scratch)
        \tikzsymbols@ifsaveboxundefined{Devilish#1#2#3}{%
          \set@tkzsymblsscl{#1}%
          \iftikzymbols@draftabsolute%
                \tksymbls@bx@Prmtrstore{#1}%
                \tikzsymbols@draftbox{1.73ex*\real{\tkzsymbls@Prmtr}}{1.909ex*\real{\tkzsymbls@Prmtr}}%
          \else%
                \ifdim\tkzsymbls@scl<0pt\set@tkzsymblsscl{-#1}\fi%
          \begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.4ex, y=2.4ex, line width=0.12ex*\tkzsymbls@scl,scale=#1]
                \fill [line width=0.05ex*\tkzsymbls@scl, #2, even odd rule] (0.25,0.47) arc (52:-52:0.17 and 0.14) (0.25,0.47) arc (50:-50:0.20 and 0.19) (-0.25,0.47) arc (128:232:0.17 and 0.14)  (-0.25,0.47) arc (130:230:0.20 and 0.19);
                \draw [line width=0.05ex*\tkzsymbls@scl, #3] (0.25,0.47) arc (52:-52:0.17 and 0.14) (0.25,0.47) arc (50:-50:0.20 and 0.19) (-0.25,0.47) arc (128:232:0.17 and 0.14)  (-0.25,0.47) arc (130:230:0.20 and 0.19);
                \fill [#2] (0,0) circle (0.33);
                \draw (0,0) circle (0.33);
                \fill (-0.1,0.075) circle (0.075);
                \fill (0.1,0.075) circle (0.075);
                \draw (-0.2,-0.1) .. controls (-0.1,-0.2) and (0.1,-0.2) .. (0.2,-0.1);
                \draw [line cap=round] (0.075,0.12) -- (0.175,0.2) (-0.075,0.12) -- (-0.175,0.2);
                \draw [line width=0.075ex*\tkzsymbls@scl, #3, -{Stealth[bend,length=#1*.4ex]}] (0.1,-.325) to [out=-90, in=-125] (.3,-.3) to [out=55, in=125] (.45,-.15) to [out=-55, in=-60] (.4,-.25) to [out=120, in=-160] (.5,-.2) to [out=20, in=-155] (.4,.175) to [out=25, in=-80] (.45,.3);
          \end{tikzpicture}%
          \fi%
        }%
        \tikzsymbols@use@box{Devilish#1#2#3}%
        \tikzsymbolsaftersymbolinput%
  }
  \tkzsymbls@Declare@Robust@Command{wDevilish}[1][3]{\Devilish[#1][opacity=0][black]}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (green) {\color{green}\Devilish[5][][green]};
    \node (red) [right=5pt of green] {\color{red}\Devilish[13][][red]};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \node [draw, fill=black, fit=(green) (red)] {};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: two devils]

Or is there really no best way in a case like this i.e. any method will be fragile just because I'm building on something provided by a package? That is, is the only real solution in this kind of case to code *all* of the symbols I want from scratch? (Or to fork `tikzsymbols`'s code and to then build on my copy of that code, which of course would not be vulnerable to future changes made to the original package.)

Comment: P.S. If I include 'best' in the title, I am warned that my question is likely to be closed even though there is a `best-practices` tag and a range of questions on this topic!

Comment: Current best method: (1) Create the characters any which way, (2) Propose them for inclusion in Unicode and get them added to the next revision of the standard, (3) Wait for a font like Symbola to support them. The process can be automated with a package I’m writing, but the compilation time for a document with a new character will necessarily be on the order of a few years. 

Comment: @J.C.Salomon (+1) For perfectionism but I think it would overburden unicode somewhat. That is, it seems unreasonable to expect all possible symbols to be officially included however idiosyncratic their use. Plus, (1-3) would not actually suit me since I want a solution I can use with (pdf)LaTeX ;). (There is just no pleasing some people....)

Comment: Somebody down-voted without comment? Because of the content (fraternising with the Devil)? Or for some technical reason? If the latter, I'd like to try to address the concern. If the former, there's not much I can say.

Answer (score 7):

`Tikzpeople` package provides `evil` and `good` option to convert into a Saint or Devil corresponding symbol. Some examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum width=1.5cm}]
\foreach \i [count=\ni] in {priest, nun, judge}
{
    \node[\i] (\i) at (0,-2.5*\ni) {};
    \node[\i, evil] (\i-evil) at (2,-2.5*\ni) {};
    \node[\i, good] (\i-saint) at (4,-2.5*\ni) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Possibly the `pic` syntax provides one fairly easy way to go:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{symbols/.cd,
  smiley/.pic={
    \draw circle [radius=1/2] (225:1/3) arc (225:315:1/3) 
      (135:1/4) circle [radius=1/32] (45:1/4) circle [radius=1/32];
  }
}
\newcommand\tikzsymbol[2][]{\tikz\pic[#1]{symbols/#2};}
\begin{document}
\tikzsymbol{smiley}
\tikzsymbol[red]{smiley}
\tikzsymbol[scale=0.5]{smiley}
\tikzsymbol[ultra thick, line cap=round]{smiley}
\tikzsymbol[xslant=.5]{smiley}
\tikzsymbol[rotate=45]{smiley}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose to answer the OP's question: this would require reimplementing all the `tikzsymbols` as I don't think it uses the `pic` syntax.

Comment: Thanks very much but, yes, that is the problem. I do like the `pic` stuff and it is very useful. I certainly use it in many other cases. This question is really more specifically about wanting to create symbols to complement existing ones in a way which is as robust as possible.