# How to draw the following attacker picture in protocol using TiKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: The attacker in protocol, how to draw the following picture using TiKZ in latex ?]
The attacker in protocol, how to draw the attacker picture using TiKZ in latex ? Alice Bob and Eva ?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Generally, questions are expected to provide a minimum working example of code that demonstrates the problem or at least one's attempt at addressing the problem, if unsuccessful.  The "do this for me" type questions are generally frowned upon.  Perhaps you could edit your question to include code for what you have tried to this point.

Comment: As Steven said, there is nothing holding you back from downloading that image and adding it to your tikz image inside a node.

Comment: Come on, downvoters, -1 makes the point; our site is filled with this kind of thing

Comment: @daleif doesn't need to be an image it could be [picture mode](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33295650#33295650)

Comment: What is protocol and who are Alice Bob and Eva? Twins?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212525/demonic-correspondence-best-practices-when-defining-devils-in-tikz?s=1|1.1448,

Comment: To answer @cfr's comment: [Alice and Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) are the two ends of a secure communication channel.  Eve is an eavesdropper.

Comment: I've seen Eve depicted as a spy with a hand cupped to her ear but can't find an example -- the original definition was "eavesdropper" not "evil".

Comment: I think you should accept the nice answer you got. You can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark left of it.

Answer (score 16):

I don't know too much about security protocols but [`tikzpeople`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzpeople) package has been designed by its author Nils Fleischhacker with this intention:

> The package was originally written to provide me with shapes of people
>   to depict parties in cryptographic protocols and security definitions
>   on beamer slides.

There's no `devil` figure, but there exist `evil` option which can provide funny results:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum width=1.5cm}]
\node[alice] (alice) {};
\node[bob, right= 4cm of alice, mirrored] (bob) {};
\draw[->, thick] (alice) -- coordinate[near start] (aux) (bob);
\node[priest, evil, mirrored, above right=-5mm and 1cm of alice] (priest) {};
\draw[->,red, ultra thick] (priest)--(aux);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I feel like the people could do with their initials on lapel badges. To make it clearer who's who

Comment: @ChrisH `\node[bob, label=bob, ...`, `\node[alice, label=alice,...`. You can see the result in [this example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338434/1952)

Comment: I was having trouble with CTAN mirrors when I posted that so couldn't RTFM and didn't find the old Q.  But now I want to contribute to tikzpeople, despite not having the skills!

Comment: @ChrisH Or, even easier: `\node[bob]{Bob}`. Node contents is shown below the figure