# Launcher icon using latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a package that compiles a latex image to an icon of Launcher for Android while maintaining screen densities?
For this in Android Studio there is
Image Asset Studio, but  no I manage to recreate the desired icon image.

Edited:
In the following image marked with arrows shows the Launcher Icon, I used the tikzpeople package, but the sharpness and resolution of the image is not good.

[image]

Comment: What is a "Launcher for Android"?

Comment: @AndréC When an app installed, an icon appears on the screen, for example, the WhatsApp icon is green with a phone drawing enclosed in a bubble.

Comment: Add a screenshot on your question, perhaps?

Comment: Look at `tikzpeople` package.

Comment: Which image format and resolution do you need for the icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting "Icons" into the packages search field on CTAN produces 17 hits

Interestingly one includes Knuth's own input [image]

but only a few are close to your request for modern App stylised output.

None will provide the android recommended / required res structure.

App studio recommends an SVG input, **See Ulrike Fischer's comment as to how this may be achieved via latex + dvisvgm.** however I found this produced an odd translucent result

**Ignore the crude graphic** note by default the collar is showing through the face [image]

For **Martin Scharrer's pdf2svg** tikzpicture method see /try his answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51766/170109
however I had problems running interactively so using on command line

I got a better opaque result (to produce this output, note it is the larger drawable-xxxhdpi since I cant upload the .svg)

So here is the [image]code

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert=pdf2svg]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[graduate,saturated,mirrored,monitor,undershirt=yellow] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

via this sequence

```
Latex logo.tex
pdf2svg logo.pdf logo.svg
```

A windows version can be found here https://github.com/jalios/pdf2svg-windows/releases

And here it is loaded in Asset Studio and the download res file with 5 perfect images will be about 55KB (well lean! 130 if you include web version)

[image]

[image][image][image]

Whatever TeX / TikZ / SVG output takes your fancy. (that last one is blochsphere)

Alternately the icon you have identified and as shown in the answer by JouleV can be modified to suit a suite of the recommended pixel sizes.

The key to pixel sharpness is choosing a large enough scale that works for Hi-Res and can be divided down to smaller sizes, whilst retaining clarity in an application such as inkscape. The set of manually reduced icons can then be loaded and modified in Image Asset Studio to add the desired rounding etc.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly what `tikzpeople` does. This is the title of [the package documentation](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzpeople/tikzpeople.pdf):

[image]

And here is the code for the picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[graduate,shield,sword] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you look at the silhouette of the pic, you may discover a duck in it. ;-) (+1)

Comment: You're not crediting CarLaTeX for saying the same thing in his commentary?

Comment: Yes, but what I meant is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kviV5.gif). ;-)

Comment: `\node[priest,evil] {};`

Comment: @marmot A note to the duck: Take care or the sword will harm you :))

Comment: Joking aside the REQUIREMENT is ideally SVG output since the OP already has that raster as his startpoint @marmot your an export :-) on Tikz

Comment: As svg seems to be the wanted end format, you should add the dvisvgm option, and compile with latex + dvisvgm.

Comment: For those interested, here is a silhouette of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msqb4.png.

Comment: @SolomonUcko Yes, a duck. ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I suggest not to use the `dvisvgm` option when compiling with latex +  dvisvgm because it often produces odd results. Instead, the default options as in the above example (implying dvips) should work just fine with dvisvgm.

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy Here you have an example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338436/1952